# ASP.NET Custom Error for 404, default for everything else

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

Currently i have the following in my web.config

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html" />
    </customErrors>
    ...
<system.web>
```

However, I want the error page that appears when `customErrors mode="Off"`, that is, the default ASP.NET error page with the full exception stacktrace, even on a remote machine. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> yes it is possible

by default,IIS will be using errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" ,we can set that to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>       
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: When using this answer, I recommend removing `<customErrors>` entirely and configure custom error pages inside `<httpErrors>`.